# Can't get items from ListAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursor

I read data from database:

```
private MyDatabase db;
private Cursor cities;
private ListAdapter cityListAdapter;
private ListView    citiesListView;

db = new MyDatabase(getContext());
cities = db.getCities();
```

And set an adapter for it:

```
cityListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        cities, 
        new String[] {"city"}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},0);

citiesListView.setAdapter(cityListAdapter);
```

I can see the `ListView` populated correctly. But when I try to get an item's string, I get a strange string instead: **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4251fac0**

Here's my code for this:

```
citiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        String str = cityListAdapter.getItem(position).toString();

        chosenCityTextView.setText(str);
    }
});
```

Why am I not getting the string that appears in the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the getItem method returns a cursor, and then you have to use getColumnIndex and getString to get the effective value of the field you want. Also see [Return object from CursorAdapter.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181730/return-object-from-cursoradapter-get)

Code example:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) cityListAdapter.getItem(position);
String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city"));
chosenCityTextView.setText(city);
```

The way you did before was calling the .toString() method on the cursor object, that is why you got that weird string (which is the address of the object in java).

Comment: You mean something like this: `Cursor cursor = (Cursor) cityListAdapter.getItem(position).getColumnIndex("city");` ? If not then please explain further...